# Angular 14 cant get grouping to work with NGRX in my reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx

So this is that state of my basket object that was built up on a 'selection' screen. I now move to my basket page where I want to group:

[image]

As you can see I have 2 records with an id 2 and another 2 with id 5. So now I'm trying to reduce my basket to be something like:

> {count: 2},{ id: 2, title: "photo 2" cost: 24.4,.....}
> {count: 1},{ id: 4, title: "photo 4" cost: 14.62,....}
> {count: 2},{ id: 5, title: "photo 5" cost: 37.24,....}

Where the first element is the count of each and then the second set of elements is the sum of each.

So for the moment, I thought I'd first try and get the second set with a group by.

in my page component I have:

```
export class BasketMobileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private basketStore: Store<{ basket: Photo[] }>) { }

  photos$ = this.basketStore.pipe(select(basket => basket.basket));
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
      
  }
}
```

This just returns the basket as is for the moment.

So now, I introduce an action:

```
export const groupBasket = createAction('[Basket Component] orderBasket', props<{ basket: Observable<Photo[]> }>());
```

I make it Observable because `photo$` in my component is observable.

then in my reducer I have:

```
export const initialBasketState: Array<Photo> = [];

export const basketReducer = createReducer(
  initialBasketState,
  on(basketDetail, (state, { basket }) => { return [...state, basket] }
  ),
  on(getBasket, (state, { id }) => state.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  ),
  on(groupBasket, (state, { basket }) => { return [...state, basket.pipe(groupBy(photo => photo.id), mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray())))] }
  )
);
```

at this point The whole statement for groupBasket red lines.

If I introduce a function:

```
function grouptheBasket(array: Observable<Photo>) {   
  return array.pipe(groupBy(photo => photo.id), mergeMap(group => group.pipe(toArray()))) 
}
```

and change my 'on' event to be:

```
 on(groupBasket, (state, { basket } ) => { return [...state, grouptheBasket(basket)]}
```

The construct of the function seems fine but the whole 'on' statement is as before and continues to red line.

The main error seems to be:

> Argument of type 'Observable<Photo[]>' is not assignable to parameter
> of type '{basket: Observable<Photo[]>;}

In my ngOnInit I Place:

```
 this.basketStore.dispatch(orderBasket(this.photos$));
```

This also errors on the this.photos$ with:

> Property 'basket' is missing in type 'Observable<Photo[]>'

but I think this is because of the error in the reducer.

Comment: You should get rid of any observables in action and reducers. You can use Effects to process observables https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#using-other-observable-sources-for-effects . And yuo can use Selectors for groupping also.

Comment: I've followed your various recent ngrx questions and answered one or two, but my observation is that you are coming up with rather unorthodox practices every time, this one probably being the worst. Maybe go back to basics and do an ngrx course if you haven't already?

Comment: When you have an observable in your component, then subscribe to it (or use the async pipe) and give the action the resolved value. The learning curve of ngrx is very steep in my opinion, but once you get the hang of it, it's easy. So as mentioned from wlf, an extra round on tutorials would not be the worst idea.